# The type constraint 'XYZ' has already been created

Tags: perl, types, moose

I want to use a [`Moose::Util::TypeConstraints`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Util::TypeConstraints) in my application.

So I define one in my `main.pl`

#### main.pl

```
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;

subtype 'mySpecialType'
    => as 'Object'
    => where sub { $_->does('something') };

use noUse;
```

In the package `noUse.pm` are packages used, which use the type constraint

#### noUse.pm

```
package noUse;

use Use1;

use Use2;

1;
```

and my package `Use1` and `Use2` are working with the type constraint

#### Use1.pm

```
package Use1; 

use Moose; 

has 'object1' => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'mySpecialType' ); 

1;
```

#### Use2.pm

```
package Use2; 

use Moose; 

has 'object2' => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'mySpecialType' ); 

1;
```

If I run `main.pl` I get this error:

> The type constraint 'mySpecialType' has already been created in Use1 and cannot be created again in main at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/Moose/Util/TypeConstraints.pm line 348
>           Moose::Util::TypeConstraints::subtype('mySpecialType', 'HASH(0x227f398)', 'HASH(0x2261140)') called at main.pl line 10

What causes this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way is to `use` the common code from the libraries where it's needed, not to let it radiate from the main program.

### MyTypes.pm

```
package MyTypes;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;
subtype 'mySpecialType'
    => as 'Object'
    => where sub { $_->does('something') };
```

### Use1.pm

```
package Use1; 
use Moose; 
use MyTypes;
has 'object1' => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'mySpecialType' ); 
1;
```

### Use2.pm

```
package Use2; 
use Moose;
use MyTypes; 
has 'object2' => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'mySpecialType' ); 
1;
```

And `main.pl` becomes just

```
use noUse;
```

`noUse.pm` stays unchanged.

See [simbabque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331451/simbabque)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41551349/1030675) for why.

Comment: Let's merge. I was going to pretty much put that at the bottom of my explanation right now. :D

Comment: @simbabque: Yeah, I wanted to add a paragraph about what happens at compile time and how Moose resolves unknown type constraints :)

Comment: I'm going to link to your answer in mine.

Comment: And now we've got a circular reference :D

Answer (score 3):

### This answer investigates why the error happens

First of all, we need to remember that Moose's type constraints are global. Moose itself keeps track of them.

It seems that Moose automatically makes Moose::Util::TypeConstraints from `isa => 'Foo'`.

I changed your code in *main.pl* to the following, [to check if this constraint already exists](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Util::TypeConstraints#find_type_constraint($type_name)).

```
use noUse;
use Data::Printer { deparse => 1 };
my $type = Moose::Util::TypeConstraints::find_type_constraint('mySpecialType');
p $type;
```

Turns out it does.

```
Moose::Meta::TypeConstraint::Class  {
    Parents       Moose::Meta::TypeConstraint
    public methods (9) : class, create_child_type, equals, get_message, is_a_type_of, is_subtype_of, meta, new, parents
    private methods (1) : _new
    internals: {
        class                      "mySpecialType",
        compiled_type_constraint   sub {
                package Eval::Closure::Sandbox_150;
                use warnings;
                use strict;
                do {
                    $_[0]->isa('mySpecialType') if &Scalar::Util::blessed($_[0])
                };
            },
        constraint                 sub {
                package Moose::Meta::TypeConstraint::Class;
                use warnings;
                use strict;
                $_[0]->isa($class_name);
            },
        _default_message           sub {
                package Moose::Meta::TypeConstraint;
                use warnings;
                use strict;
                my $value = shift();
                my $can_partialdump = try(sub {
                    require Devel::PartialDump;
                    'Devel::PartialDump'->VERSION(0.14);
                    1;
                }
                );
                if ($can_partialdump) {
                    $value = 'Devel::PartialDump'->new->dump($value);
                }
                else {
                    $value = defined $value ? overload::StrVal($value) : 'undef';
                }
                return q[Validation failed for '] . $name . "' with value $value";
            },
        inline_environment         {},
        inlined                    sub {
                package Moose::Meta::TypeConstraint::Class;
                use warnings;
                use strict;
                my $self = shift();
                my $val = shift();
                return 'Scalar::Util::blessed(' . $val . ')' . ' && ' . $val . '->isa(' . B::perlstring($self->class) . ')';
            },
        name                       "mySpecialType",
        package_defined_in         "Use1",
        parent                     Moose::Meta::TypeConstraint
    }
}
```

This is a simple `isa` check that Moose seems to put in if no other constraint already exists with that name. That way, you can do stuff like this.

```
use Moose;
has date => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'DateTime' );
```

The order of execution in our original *main.pl* is the problem, because `use` gets done at *compile time*.

Here is your error again, with emphasis.

> type constraint 'mySpecialType' **has already been created in Use1** and cannot be created again in main

Let's take a look what is going on when *main.pl* gets run. I am ignoring Moose itself and other modules in the below analysis, which is highly simplified.

- *compile time*: *main.pl* line 1 `use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;`

  - that module gets loaded, a bunch of things happen, we ignore those
- *compile time*: *main.pl* line 6 `use noUse;`

  - *compile time*: *noUse.pm* line 2 `use Use1;`

    - *compile time*: *Use1.pm* line 2 `use Moose;`

      - Moose gets loaded, a bunch of things happen, we ignore those
    - *run time*: *Use1.pm* line 3 `has 'object1' ...` puts the attribute `object1` into the `Use1` class. At this point Moose checks if there is a type constraint for `mySpecialType` and then makes one with an `isa` check because it asumes this is a package name.
  - *compile time*: *noUse.pm* line 3 `use Use2;`

    - *compile time*: *Use2.pm* line 2 `use Moose;`

      - Moose gets loaded, a bunch of things happen, we ignore those
    - *run time*: *Use2.pm* line 3 `has 'object2' ...` puts the attribute `object2` into the `Use2` class. At this point Moose checks if there is a type constraint for `mySpecialType` and there is (because it was created in `Use1.pm`).
- *run time*: *main.pl* line 2ff `subtype 'mySpecialType' ...` tries to create a type constraint `mySpecialType`. This fails, because there already is one. It was created in `Use1.pm`. BOOM.

So the problem is that the code in packages that are `use`d in *main.pl* gets run before the normal code in *main.pl*. You need to declare your types before they are encountered at *run time* the first time.

Let's prove this by doing a dirty hack.

```
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;

BEGIN {
    subtype 'mySpecialType' => as 'Object' => where sub { $_->does('something') };
}

use noUse;
```

This will not blow up, because the `BEGIN` block gets run at *compile time*, which is before the `use noUse` statement. Therefore the type constraint will already be there when Moose encounters it the first time in a `has => ( ... isa => 'mySpecialType' )` construct.

But that's not pretty. let's try another solution.
    use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;

```
subtype 'mySpecialType' => as 'Object' => where sub { $_->does('something') };

require noUse;
```

This will also work, because the `require` is not called at *compile time*, but at *run time*. So the `subtype` gets installed first, and then it will load `noUse`. But this defers loading all your classes until we are already in run time in your main program, and that is bad form.

**They correct way to do this** is to put all your types into a *type library* and load that one first. See [choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41551350/1331451) for how to do that.

For good measure, you should also `use` that type library module in all modules that use any of the types. That way you ensure that in the future, when you write other applications with the same classes, you don't need to remember to load that type library. **Always `use` everything you need for a class in that class.**

Comment: @Borodin you accidentally deleted half my answer with your edit ;)

Comment: Oops :( I'll leave it to you!

Comment: @Borodin don't worry about it. Thanks for trying to help. :)

Comment: So to be clear, you're saying that a constraint called `mySpecialType` is already hard-coded into `Moose`? That's horrible.

Comment: No @borodin. I'm saying that when an attribute in a Moose based class has a an `isa` value that is not a type constraint Moohse Moose creates one with that name to do an `isa` check. The deparse in my debug output shows that. And when that happens before you install one yourself, you can't create it any more because you can't seem to overwrite them.

Comment: That sounds like it's hard-coded into `Moose`. How else does it choose `mySpecialType` as an identifier? Are we being confused by language differences? It should at least use an empty string while forbidding empty strings, or some similar device.

Comment: @borodin I don't know if we are. Reread the huge list. It explains the execution order of the code from question. There is an attribute `has foo => ( isa => 'mySpecialType')`in a class that gets loaded before the code in main.pl. Moose created a type constraint already, so it crashes.

Comment: Then I'm not understanding `Moose` properly. What list are you referring to? That line of code looks exactly like what I meant -- a hard-coded value. Are you saying that doing it that way is fine because it will crash only in the case of a wrong loading order? Then that should be trapped and reported as such by the module. I would go for something like an empty string, as I said, or perhaps `\undef`, which should (?) never be the same twice. Why do you think it's okay? Someone has accidentally encountered an internal value and the resulting error message doesn't relate to the problem.

Comment: I think we need a chat to clear this up @borodin. Maybe I don't understand you properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132735/discussion-between-borodin-and-simbabque).

Comment: @simbabque Thank you for your explanation. It explains why this error happens and choroba's answer gives a solution. However, This is a bug in my opinion. If I happen to define a type constraint that perhaps matches someone else's type constraint name anywhere in all the packages I use, it will break my code (and it happens at run time), which leaves my code vulnerable. This is a bad situation to be in. I wish there is a better way of managing namespaces in Moose.

Comment: @BReddy A non-global types solution for Moose (and Moo, etc) is to use Type::Tiny, which is excellent.